# Run python file through bash file called from java programm

Tags: java, python, linux, bash, shell

I am running a bash file from a java file using the command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash run.sh "+args[0]);
```

The bash file is getting executed completely, if I run it from terminal.
But when I run it from java file, it is able to execute all commands except: `python hello.py`. I don't understand why.

The java code is as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
public class runTheTextConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash run.sh "+args[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The bash file run.sh contains the following command:

```
python hello.py
```

Python file contains a single line:

```
print "Hello"
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you edit your question and include 1. A tiny hello.py, 2. A tiny java file that just runs `python hello.py`, 3. A copy of the command you use to compile and run the java file. 4. The output you get. 5. The output you expected to get. 6. An explanation of the difference? Try to avoid copy-pasting just one method from your big Java file (because then we can't try it ourselves).

Comment: What happens when the java app gets to running the python script? Do you get an error? Do things in the bash script *after* the python script run correctly?

Comment: No, I dont get any error and there is no output displayed. But when I directly run the bash file, then I get the output.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` returns a [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object. Please redirect its output and error streams to standard output and error streams (ex. using [this StreamGobbler class](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2)) and include the output in your question.